# Normaliser of Wreath Product of Matrix Group

Tags: group-theory, wreath-product

I was reading and doing some problems on [wreath products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product). The groups are matrix group in my case.

> Let $G_s=GL(2^s,R)$ denotes the group of invertible matrices over $R$ and suppose $M\le G_s$ for some positive number $s$ and some $R$ which is commutative with identity. Also suppose $C_2$ be the cyclic group of order $2$ generated by the permutation $(1,2)$. Then we consider the wreath product $M'=M\wr C_2 \le G_{s+1}$.

Now my question is

> If $N$ and $N'$ are the normaliser of $M$ and $M'$ in $G_s$ and $G_{s+1}$ respectively, then is it true that $N'\le N\wr C_2$? Even if not true in general, is it true for some special case, say, when the base group of $M'$ is characteristic in $M'$?

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Addendum:** From the answer of Derek Holt, it is clear that the above is not true even if the base group of $M′$ is characteristic in $M'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a counterexample, let $M = C_3 \times C_3 \le {\rm GL}(2,7)$, where $M$ consists of diagonal matrices, and $M' = M \wr C_2$.

Then $N'$ contains, for example, the permutation matrix that interchanges the first and third basis vectors and fixes the second and fourth, and this does not lie in ${\rm GL}(2,7) \wr C_2$.

Note that the base group of $M'$ has order $3^4$ and is of index $2$ in $M'$, so it is characteristic.

Comment: Thanks. I understand. A quick question, sorry. So is the reason that this counter example works because field is finite? I mean can we get same type of counter example even in infinite fields/rings?

Comment: May be I should rephrase the original question, it seems that if the base group $B$ of $M'$ is characteristic in $M'$ then $N'\le N_{GL(2^{s+1},R)}(B)$, is it true? I have checked in GAP for the above counter example and it happens to be true. Sorry again for another question.

Comment: There is no need for the field to be finite. The counterexample works in any field containing a cube root of $1$. Isn't the answer to your new question clearly yes by the definition of characteristic subgroup?

Comment: Thanks. Oh yes, I get it, I will remove the new question, I missed the argument. Thanks again.